# How to query a table with square brackets in it?

Tags: sql-server

How can I query a table literally called `[tbl]` with the square brackets in its name?

I'm trying

```
select * from [[tbl]]
```

But that doesn't work. Nor does

```
select * from [\[tbl\]]
```

How else would I escape the `[`s?

Comment: Why would someone name a table like that?

Comment: @Stijn Because they wanted to make sure their query builder worked correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Through trial and error, I discovered you have to double the number of closing `]`s only. i.e.

```
select * from [[tbl]]]
```

Comment: Its good to know how to get around a situation like this, but you should really fix the problem, Name your tables correctly :)

Comment: @M.Ali I deliberately concocted the situation so I could find the solution. Nevertheless, you should see some of the data I have to work with; lots of tables with spaces, two spaces in a row, leading and trailing spaces, quotes, you name it. Sometimes these things come from a 3rd party and you just have to deal with it ;)

Comment: @M.Ali: sp_rename can mess things up as well if you put brackets into the new name accidently. This happend to me by mistake.